# Create jQuery array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Have a code that updates a textarea:

```
var input_baseprice = $('.active .input_baseprice').html();

$('[name=baseprice]').html(input_baseprice);
```

However, when there are many `.input_baseprice` elements, the textarea gets content only from the first one.

How can I automate creation of `input_baseprice*` to get:

```
$('[name=baseprice]').html(input_baseprice + '<br>' + input_baseprice2 + '<br>' + input_baseprice3 ...);
```

?

Comment: So many great variants! Thanks a lot for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is documented in the api notes http://api.jquery.com/html/

> In order for the following 's content to be retrieved

Try this

```
var html = '';

$('.active .input_baseprice').each( function () {
    html += $( this ).html();
});

$('[name=baseprice]').html( html );
```

After re-reading your question, you may need to swap our `.html()` for `.val()` depending upon the type of element you are dealing with

Answer (score 2):

Use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method, then join them.

```
$('[name=baseprice]').html($('.active .input_baseprice').map(function() {
  return $(this).html();
}).get().join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

use each to loop thrrough the textarea content... `.val()` should work 
try this

```
var str="";

$('.active .input_baseprice').each(function(){
      str += $(this).val();
 });

$('[name=baseprice]').val( str);
```

**OR**

in array ..

```
var temparray= [];

$('.input_baseprice').each(function(){
   temparray.push($(this).html());
}

 $('[name=baseprice]').html(temparray.join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the each() function to loop through each element and append the data to an array, which will then be combined into a string:

```
var data = [];

$('.input_baseprice').each(function(){
    data.push($(this).html());
}

$('[name=baseprice]').html(data.join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also create array by [`jQuery.makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)

```
 var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elements);
```